# React native control tab navigation with button click

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-navigation

How can i move to specific tab when click on button. I'm fetching the tabs from an API. All tabs containing only one screen with different data

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `react-navigation` you can just use

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Name_of_Tab')
```

You can read more about it [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigate-link-to-other-screens)

Below is the code of a working example. At the bottom you will find a link to a snack showing it working.

## App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import AppContainer from './MainNavigation';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}
```

## MainNavigation.js

```
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';

import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

// create TabNavigator
const screens = {
  Tab1: {
    screen: Screen1
  },
  Tab2: {
    screen: Screen2
  }
};

const config = {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Tab1'
};


const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(screens, config);
export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

## Screen1.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Screen extends React.Component {

  onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Tab2') // this will navigate to Tab2
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Tab 1</Text>
        <Button title={'Switch tab'} onPress={this.onPress} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
});
```

## Screen2.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Screen extends React.Component {

  onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Tab1') // this will navigate to Tab1
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Tab 2</Text>
        <Button title={'Switch tab'} onPress={this.onPress} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
});
```

Here is it in snack so you can see it working:

https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/navigating-to-new-tab

Comment: perfect . I am looking for that but in react-native-tabbar-bottom but not able to implement it , Any reference?

Comment: Sorry, I’ve never used react-native-tabbar-bottom, so I cannot help you.

Comment: This is the right awnser and helped me a lot. please do the checkmark for the other community members. @Vamsi